# xamarin forms - differentiatre between left and right swipe in C#, PanGestureRecognizer

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, swipe-gesture

I have added a pan gesture recognizer to an image to allow users to swipe though a list of images (I'm aware of CarouselView but we're not using it in this instance).

I have 2 questions about the pan gesture:

1. when debugging I notice that each swipe cause the code to fire 4 times, so I've had to add the panCount to get round that but I really don't like it, is there any other way to get it to run only once?
2. The code fires no matter what direction the swipe, I need to differentiate between left and right, how can I do this?

> ```
> panGesture.PanUpdated += (s, e) =>
>         {
>             if(panCount == 0)
>             {
>               string x = bigImg.Source.ToString();
>               int _i = Convert.ToInt32(x.Substring(x.Length - 1)) ;
>               OnImgSwiped(_i, _venueName, imgSource); // updates the image
>             }
>             panCount++;
>             if(panCount == 4)
>             {
>                 panCount = 0;
>             }
>         };
>         MyImage.GestureRecognizers.Add(panGesture);
> ```